# Does an empty const constructor matter?

Tags: dart

This is a follow-up question to

- [How does the const constructor actually work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339923/place-preamble-packages-in-a-different-tex-file),

So far from what I've read about `const` constructors in Dart, it ensures that only one object of the class in question is allocated. In theory, this can save allocation space and execution time. It's even recommended to apply it wherever possible when following [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#consider-making-your-constructor-const-if-the-class-supports-it) design.

Now, say we have a stateless widget `Foo`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Hello world");
  }
}
```

Without defining an explicit `const` constructor, this widget cannot be used in a `const` context. In other words, the following snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Foo();
  }
}
```

is illegal. But is there even a benefit to adding a `const Foo();` to the `Foo` class if it doesn't (and won't have) any fields in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a benefit. You should declare as const if possible.

According to the [Flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html):

> Use const widgets where possible, and provide a const constructor for the widget so that users of the widget can also do so.

The benefits are the same as having a default vs const constructor:

1. Performance ([see](https://crizantlai.medium.com/flutter-performance-analysis-of-const-constructor-d2a72fd8a043))
2. Your code is consistent and sound
3. Are used as annotations
4. Can use in compile switch

You can enable const by default using [Lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors.html)

Comment: According to your performance link, there's indeed a difference when there's a large number of widgets to render. However, whether it's something the user notices or if it has any impact is case-by-case.
My take away is that unless you're dealing with a large amount of widgets (ex. a very big list being eagerly rendered), then it's not necessary.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 3. and 4.? Is it documented in the Flutter doc.?

Comment: 'unless you're dealing with a large amount of widgets then it's not necessary' apparently you know more than the flutter team since your recommendation is symmetrical opposite their recommendation.

Comment: It wasn't a recommendation. It's a subjective conclusion based on your performance link and the Flutter documentation.
What's your sources on point 3 and 4?